# How do I reset the input field after clicking to send my message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

In a chat app, I would like to reset() the input field where I send messages upon cliking so the input field will become empty again. Here's what I have.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(""); 
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

```
const submit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
socket.emit("text-message", message);
    };
```

```
<form onSubmit={submit} id="form">
    <div className="input-group">
        <input
            name="message"
            maxLength="60"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Message"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => {
            setMessage(e.currentTarget.value);
             }} 
            value={message}
            id="text"
            />
     <button id="send" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
        Send
     </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you just set the message in your submit function after submit is successful? i.e. `setMessage('')`. Or did you need something more advanced?

Comment: That did it, more simple than expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up from my comment so this can be flagged as answered. I'll attempt to explain in a bit more detail so that anyone with a similar issue might find the answer more useful.

Using the value prop on an input means that it is "[Controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)".

This means what ever you provided to the value prop is what will appear in the input.

So changing the value appearing in the input is as simple as changing the variable being used for the value prop, in this case `message`.

As `message` is created by `useState` the correct way to update it is using the corresponding setState method, in this case `setMessage`. This is already being used in the snippet above in the onChange event `setMessage(e.currentTarget.value);` to handle updating `message` as the user enters data.

A basic reset with no special logic can be achieved using `setMessage('');` added to the end of the `submit` function which is used to action the form.

```js
const submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('text-message', message);
    setMessage('');
};
```